# Rails: issue with controller#action when using slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slug

I'm using slugs to 'humanize' my ids for my restaurants controller.

I test to see if a slug exists and then display that restaurants information on the show.html.erb page. However, when I try to do a 'restaurants/new' it interprets the 'new' as a slug and has an error.

How can I use slugs with 'restaurants/:slug/' and have 'restaurants/new' redirect to the Create New Restaurant page?

restaurants_controller.rb:

```
def show
    if Restaurant.exists?(:slug => params[:slug])
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:slug])
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Restaurant does not exist"
        redirect_to action: :index
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/routes.rb`, you'll want the `get '/restaurants/new'` line to be before the `get 'restaurants/:slug'` line, as the routes are parsed in the order they appear in the file.